# Does language fallback work for rendering variant fields?

Tags: sxa, language-fallback

I have created a rendering variant in 'en' and enabled item fallback. But when I tried to access the rendering variant with other language like `fr-fr`, all the rendering variant fields are not displaying data properly.

For example, any prefix /suffix field data, the `Text` of a `VariantText` field, or Template variant field is not getting rendered. If I create `fr-fr` version then only its working.

Is there any way to fix this so that my rendering variant will be in English with fallback enabled and it will work for other languages?

Comment: It should work..  can you see fallback versions in the editor? If not, is "Enable Item Fallback" checked on the variant item?